# Resume Flow to the CurrentElement step

Tags: visual-workflow, flow-interviews

I am querying for `CurrentElement` on [FlowInterview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_flowinterview.htm). Now is there a way to pass that CurrentElement into the flow interface in salesforce and tell it to resume the flow from that step?

The scenario is the user started the flow, then they paused it. Next time they come back and click a custom button "I want to resume where I left off" so then I query for the `CurrentElement` and the flow resumes at that step.

Comment: Isn't this the way to do this - [Customize Resume Paused Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_pausedid.htm#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20users%20can%20resume,component.)?

Comment: I think you are right except I want to do it with LWC. It appears that there's no support for that but I can do it using aura. Thanks for the link.